# Power BI Query Editor: Replace a value on a column base on multiple criteria in different columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table that looks like this:

Id GroupId Indicator Boolean
1 A Intl Y
2 B Dom N
3 A Intl N
4 A Intl N
5 B Dom Y
6 A Intl N
7 C Intl N
8 C Intl N

What I need if a transformation that will change my Boolean as follow:
If a GroupId with a "Intl" Indicator has at least one row with a Boolean at Y, all the row with the same GroupId get the Y.

My final table should look like this below, where Ids 3,4 and 6 had their Boolean changed to Y.

Id GroupId Indicator Boolean
1 A Intl Y
2 B Dom N
3 A Intl Y
4 A Intl Y
5 B Dom Y
6 A Intl Y
7 C Intl N
8 C Intl N

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {"GroupId"}, {"temp", each let x = List.Contains([Boolean],"Y")
                                                           in if x then Table.ReplaceValue(_,each [Indicator] = "Intl",0,(a,b,c)=>if b then "Y" else a,{"Boolean"}) else _}),
    combine = Table.Sort(Table.Combine(group[temp]),{"Id", 0})
in
    combine
```

[image]